# Can anyone tell me the name of a cartoon/anime in which a blond 10 year old finds something on the road and becomes an adult?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember watching a cartoon (idk if it was an anime) on Netflix in which a 10-year-old blonde girl finds like a plushie on the road and picks it up. But the plushie is actually a prince who was banished from his kingdom by his mother. The plushie/prince can talk too. Then the prince somehow gives her some powers using which she can turn into an adult and help people.

Now, this girl is like in a school club, and she makes two friends there. The two friends also get the powers and become adults to help people. I think one of them had orange hair and the other black. One of the girls was also very energetic.

Now this prince can only turn into human sometimes and the prince and the blonde have something going on. The prince also has a brother I think??

This was the basic plot I remember.

I also remember that in one episode they help an overweight girl lose weight so that she can ask out her crush. The orange haired one turns into an adult and starts coaching her.

Note: I'm not asking about LoliRock

Answer (score 4):

This is my other account and I found the name of the show by myself. It's called *[Flowering Heart](https://flowering-heart.fandom.com/wiki/Flowering_Heart_(series))* btw for those who are also searching for it.

> The first season of the Flowering Heart series which first premiered on February 26th, 2016 and ran for 26 episodes. It received a redub as well as an English dub. With the world of magic being slowly corrupted by Hopeless Energy, Prince Chess flees to the Human World to prevent the withering of the Heart Flower. Three fifth-graders of the Problem Solving Club, Ari, Suha, and Min, finds him as a strange-looking hamster form. They later team up to collect Hopeful Energy to save Flowering Kingdom. Unbeknownst to them, Prince Trump and Shuel, their enemies, are seeking Hopeless Energy.

Comment: Normally, I'd suggest merging accounts, but [deleting accounts is supposed to be irreversible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394190/901083), so it's apparently uncommon to be able to get it back to merge. Nevertheless, thank you for letting us know you found the answer.

Comment: I made a guess that this is the right *Flowering Heart*. If not, we'd appreciate if you could [edit] in the correct one, and a summary of how it matches.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots The account isn't deleted—it just never existed on this site. They should request a merge with [their Anime SE account](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/70459/lavanya0802).

Comment: Ah. I stand corrected. In which case, [how to request an account merge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) so that you can accept your answer.

Comment: Sorry, this is a story where a blond rich boy named Trump is trying to take over? Voting to close as not science fiction or fantasy.